Use AWS Managed AD in the Delegated Admin account as the identity source for IAM Identity Center - Possible?
Goal: I'm trying to switch IAM Identity Center (IIC) to use an AWS Managed Active Directory (MAD) as its identity source.
I'm using AWS Organizations as well. I'd prefer not to deploy MAD into the AWS Org' Management account.
Docs say that MAD must be in the same region as the IIC instance - check.
Docs also say that either MAD must be in the mgmt account or in the delegated admin account. (BTW, I'm interpreting it as "or". If you read those docs, they don't say "OR"; they are a bullet point list that implies all of the things, and there are contradictory things in that list.)
So I configured the acct with MAD as the delegated admin acct. No dice. When you attempt to switch identity source in IIC, that MAD dir does not appear.
Anyone have any success with this?
Thx!


Update: Found a working solution where I stood up an AD Connector in the management account and pointed it to the Managed AD in the other account. Ideally, I wouldn't have to do this, but for now it appears to be what's possible without the MAD actually being in the mgmt account.
